# Read PDF metadata using PyPDF2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, metadata, pypdf

I've tried to extract metadata with PyPDF2 and `pdfminer.six` and got:

```py
reader = PdfFileReader("example.pdf")
info = pdf.getDocumentInfo()
```

gets response:

```
{'/Title': IndirectObject(38, 0), '/Author': IndirectObject(40, 0), '/Subject': IndirectObject(41, 0), '/Producer': IndirectObject(39, 0), '/Creator': IndirectObject(42, 0), '/CreationDate': IndirectObject(43, 0), '/ModDate': IndirectObject(43, 0)}
```

### Using pdfrw

With `pdfrw` it worked like this:

```
from pdfrw import PdfReader
>>> PdfReader(<filename>).Info
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: sorry! Actually i've shared solution

Answer (score 0):

This is now part of the [PyPDF2 docs](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/metadata.html):

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

reader = PdfFileReader("example.pdf")

info = reader.getDocumentInfo()

print(reader.numPages)

# All of the following could be None!
print(info.author)
print(info.creator)
print(info.producer)
print(info.subject)
print(info.title)
```